# Duda con formulario PHP

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Necesito ayuda con un formulario en **PHP**. Estoy desarrollando un `plugin` para **wordpress** que consiste en la reserva de una Fecha y Hora determinada.

Después de seleccionar la fecha y la hora, relleno un pequeño formulario recogiendo los datos del usuario y al darle a finalizar muestro una página de agradecimiento.

Hasta hay todo bien, el problema que tengo es que si en esa página de agradecimiento la actualizo, no se vacían las variables $_POST del formulario anterior. ¿Como puedo vaciar esas variables una vez que he operado con ellas?

Gracias de antemano.
Un saludo.

Comment: Usas AJAX? Es envío por formulario nativo? Tu pregunta es muy amplia, agrega el código que llevas. A ciegas yo te diría haz `$_POST = array();` en la página de agradecimiento, pero siempre tiene que ver con tu arquitectura

Comment: Gracias Alberto!! Por ahora es un form nativo. Voy a intentar hacer lo que me comentas, creo que esa solución me valdría perfectamente. Lo probaré y comento. Gracias!!! A propósito... Cómo podría implantar un form builder en mi plugin???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que estas buscando es limpiar la variable $_POST[] este codigo que hice puede servirte, el $_POST es un arreglo asociativo y con el comando isset() lo puedes limpiar y luego le asignas nuevamente su estructura array().

Ejemplo de codigo (formulario):

```html
<form action='registro.php' method='post'>
    <labeL>Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre"><br>
    <labeL>Apellido:</label>
    <input type="text" name="apellido"><br>
    <h3>Limpiar POST</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="limpiar" value="SI" checked>SI<br>
    <input type="radio" name="limpiar" value="NO"> NO<br>
    <br><br>
    <input type='submit' value='enviar'> 
</form>
```

codigo del archivo registro.php para leer el $_POST[]

```html
<?php
if ($_POST['limpiar']=='SI') {
    unset($_POST); // limpia
    $_POST = array(); // pone valor original
}

print_r($_POST);
?>
```